# How do I copy and paste a text address in the messages app?

Tags: iphone, messages, ios

When I get a standard text I can tap and hold the message > Copy.  Now the message is on the clipboard and ready to use.  If I perform the same action on an address I am brought to the Maps application (an app I do not use).  I can create a custom Message, twitter, facebook etc...but no copy option.

How can I copy and paste a physical address on an iPhone?

#### My common use cases

- Copy as human readable text to another human as a text message
- Copy and paste into Waze
- Copy and paste into any app that needs an address

Comment: What version of iOS are you on? When I tap and hold on an address in a Message on iOS 10.2, I have the options: Get Directions, Open in Maps, Add to Contacts, and Copy.

Comment: @PseudoSu - I have 10.1.1.  It could be something buried in the Map app settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it's just the way you're pressing on it that's causing you the problem.

Assuming iOS has recognised it as an address (typically it would appear in blue and be underlined just like a traditional hyperlink), just **tap on it gently for about a second or so** and you should get a range of options. One of the options will be *Copy*. Select that and you can then paste the address as you want into another app etc.

If you just do a quick tap, then it'll take you to the Maps app as you describe.

Comment: You're almost exactly right. I was pressing too hard. I ended up triggering the pressure sensing

Comment: That's what I thought - hence why I used the word _gently_. Glad it's working for you now - I imagine it was very frustrating!

Comment: This stopped being valid.  The @KenMills answer from 2017 now is the one which works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press and hold the address.  Then when the maps window opens while still holding down, swipe up.  The additional options to Get Directions,  Open in Maps, Add to Contacts, and Copy appear at the bottom of the screen.